# Which statuses a Resque job can have?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I am using [resque-status gem](https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status) to get the status of a Resque job, however I fail to see/find which are all the possibility statuses a job can have.

I know two of them: **completed** and **failed**, but where is the list of all of them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [complete list](https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status/blob/5506df79baed45e1f5932ff0455aa8a575002db3/lib/resque/plugins/status/hash.rb#L193) of statuses seems to be

- queued
- working
- completed
- failed
- killed